# Why does my code skip all the ifs and go straight to the else statement even tho the requirements of if statement were met?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random 
                player=""
                com=""
                start = input("Press enter to start")
                def bj():   
                    com = random.choice([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
                    print(com)
                    player = input("Hit/Stand/Forfeit: ").lower()
                    
                    print(player)
                
                def stand():
                    if player_value > com and player_value != 22:
                        print("You win")
```

> I already wrote player != "forfeit". But even when player is not "forfeit", it still runs

```
while player != 22 or player != "forfeit":
         bj()
```

Here are the conditions. Even if you type "hit"/"forfeit"/"stand", it goes straight to else.

```
if player == "hit":
            player_value = random.choice([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
         elif player == "stand" or player == 22:
            stand()
            break   
         elif player == "forfeit":
              break
         else:
             print("Invalid. Try again")   
             print("----------------------")
```

Comment: You need to put `global player` at the top of your functions if you're trying to modify the global `player` variable.

Comment: Oh. So you mean like add a global behind player?
player=""

Comment: You need to have `global player, com` in both the functions `bj()` and `stand()`.

Comment: @DrippyDino You need `global player` at the top of each function to modify `player` inside the function, yes.

Comment: But if I put global player in bj() or stand(), I will have a error "expected parameter name" invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

A variable cannot be two values at once.  Since your condition is checking that it's not equal to two different values, one or the other piece is guaranteed to be true.  You probably wanted:

```
player != 22 and player != "forfeit"
#            ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
import random


def stand():
    print('stand')


player = 'hit' # Test different player values.
while True:
    if player == "hit":
        player_value = random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
        break # This break is required. Was not in the example code.
    elif player == "stand" or player == 22:
        stand()
        break
    elif player == "forfeit":
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid. Try again")
        print("----------------------")
```

Comment: If the answer misses the issue, can you edit the question and add the complete code? I could not generate the complete code myself from the example pieces.